# VBA UBound returns a negative value

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong...

I have a word document open (in word 2010) with three tables in it. I wanted to test basic table extraction in VBA and followed the instructions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa537149(v=office.11).aspx.

```
    Sub ExtractTableData()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim tbl As Word.Table
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim sData As String
    Dim aData1() As String
    Dim aData2() As String
    Dim aDataAll() As String
    Dim nrRecs As Long
    Dim nrFields As Long
    Dim lRecs As Long
    Dim lFields As Long

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set tbl = doc.Tables(1)
    Set rng = tbl.ConvertToText(Separator:=vbTab, _
        NestedTables:=False)
    ' Pick up the delimited text into and put it into a string variable.
    sData = rng.Text
    ' Restore the original table.
    doc.Undo
    ' Strip off last paragraph mark.
    sData = Mid(sData, 1, Len(sData) - 1)
    ' Break up each table row into an array element.
    aData1() = Split(sData, vbCr)
    nrRecs = UBound(aData1())
    ' The messagebox below is for debugging purposes and tells you
    ' how many rows are in the table.  It is commented out but can
    ' be used simply by uncommenting it.
    'MsgBox "The table contained " & nrRecs + 1 & " rows"
    'Process each row to break down the field information
    'into another array.
    For lRecs = LBound(aData1()) To nrRecs
        aData2() = Split(aData1(lRecs), vbTab)
        ' We need to do this only once!
        If lRecs = LBound(aData1()) Then
            nrFields = UBound(aData2())
            ReDim Preserve aDataAll(nrRecs, nrFields)
        End If
        ' Now bring the row and field information together
        ' in a single, two-dimensional array.
        For lFields = LBound(aData2()) To nrFields
            aDataAll(lRecs, lFields) = aData2(j)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I'm getting an error at this line: ReDim Preserve aDataAll(nrRecs, nrFields), which is due to "nrFields" being set to a negative value (-1)...

No idea how the upper bound of the array is a negative value... Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - I was trying to extract a nested table. I had to cycle through all sub-tables and extract individually. Also, I had to search for and remove `^p` before extraction to retain table structure.

After I had figured it out, I noticed that the MS code sample had an error: `aData2(j)` should actually be `aData2(lFields)`.

Hope this helps some other newbie!

Answer (score 1):

If UBound is -1 and LBound = 0, the array is empty.  You can generate an empty array as follows:

```
Dim EmptyArray() As String
Dim s As String
EmptyArray = Split("")
Debug.Print (UBound(EmptyArray)) ' displays -1
Debug.Print (LBound(EmptyArray)) ' displays 0
```

In your case I suspect you need to skip the processing if the array is empty:

```
aData1 = Split(...)
If (UBound(aData1) < LBound(aData1) Then
    ' UBound is -1 and LBound is 0, array is empty, nothing to do
Else
    ' Array is non-empty, do your stuff
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Although quite bizarre, it is possible for VARIANT SAFEARRAY to have negative lower *and* upper bound values for any of the dimensions. The array *extent* is LBound(,dimension) to UBound(,dimension).

What must be true is UBound >= LBound.

To get the array size, use UBound - LBound + 1.

It used to be convention to set the lower bound using an `Option Base` statement at the top of VBA code although, of course, that didn't affect arrays being returned by 3rd party libraries. Most folk used to use 1 as the lower bound.

Comment: Hmmm - something is certainly wrong with my document: if I insert the following line:
 `MsgBox ("UBound: " & UBound(aData2()) & ". LBound: " & LBound(aData1()))`
I'm getting UBound: -1. LBound: 0.

Comment: "What must be true is UBound >= LBound." - unless the array is empty, see my answer.